# Are there any Christian denominations that reject some of the gospels in the New Testament?

Tags: denomination-survey, gospels, sect

Are all four gospels in the NT accepted by every Christian denomination (whether trinitarian or non-trinitarian)? For example, you could have a christian denomination that accepts Mark’s gospel but rejects the other gospels. I don’t know for sure. These are just speculations.

Comment: Welcome Lincoln, and nice question! Thanks for taking the tour.  If you get a chance, you might find it helpful to learn more about [how we are different from other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/21576). Again, welcome!

Comment: Perhaps some denomination might reject a certain passage of one of the Gospels, but not any one Gospel in itself.

Comment: I don't know if "there are" but certainly "there were" denominations that rejected  some of the gospels, like Catharism and Marcionism.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any evidence for whole denominations which reject any of the Gospels, however among scholars the most contestable book tends to be the book of John. In particular the authorship and age of the book of John is a controversial subject - and if you consider this to be an important factor in whether John is a genuine gospel, then this will affect whether or not you accept the book as inspired.

As I say though, this isn't really a denominational issue so much as a scholarly one.

There have been issues with some of the letters on the other hand - for instance Martin Luther originally had issue with the inclusion of Hebrews, James, Jude and Revelation. Also Syriac Christian traditions didn't initially accept 2 Peter, 2 John, 3 John, Jude and Revelation. Both of these traditions ultimately came to accept these though - the main difference remaining is over the Deuterocanonical books which are included by Catholic/Greek Orthodox traditions but only deemed "useful for reading" and removed from the Biblical Canon in the Protestant traditions.

Comment: But scholarly views aside, every denomination (both trinitarian and non-trinitarian) believes that all 4 gospels are divinely inspired?

Comment: @Lincoln yes, that's what I'm getting at. I just figured it was polite to give more detail than essentially a "No" : p. I can't guarantee that there isn't some tiny sect within a denomination somewhere, or some small offshoot of a denomination, that disagrees. But among bodies of churches large enough to be called "denominations", there don't seem to be any which do not believe all 4 gospels are equally inspired

Comment: @KorvinStarmast hopefully that's a bit clearer - I tried to make it fairly neutral before as to whether the books were added by one party or removed by the other as I wasn't quite sure which was more accurate

Comment: @dani  I was being a little nit picky: your edit presents the current state of play nicely.  Comment removed.

Comment: Are there any websites that have more info on this? Surely, if there is some sect or a denomination that rejects some gospels and accept others (from within the NT), it should be written down somewhere.

Comment: @Lincoln that was my thinking too. I can't find any- even with a Google search like "denominations that reject a gospel". The closest I got was a web page about "why we should reject the gospel John" but it turned out even this was an argument for Islam, rather than a Christian sect.  There are plenty of liberal groups who hold to a more loose idea of the "inspiration" of the scriptures, so in a way you could argue that they don't really believe in the biblical canon in the same way as other denominations- but even they take the same approach to the whole Bible, not the gospels in particular